# WCF soap 1.2 with net 6.0 / BasicHttpBinding

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, .net-6.0

I need to connect to an endpoint that uses SOAP 1.2 and certificate authentication.
When I use `WSHttpBinding`, I receive the warning `SOAP header Action was not understood`. When I use `BasicHttpBinding`, I am receiving `SOAP divergence returns`, since it should not be 1.1 but 1.2.

I tried to use `CustomBinding` with the code below, however I can't change it to work with Certificate and that's why I receive the error `The username was not provided. Specify the username in ClientCredentials`.

Also tried I tried using `WSHttpBinding` and various code combinations to make `BasicHttpBinding` work with Soap12

```
TransportBindingElement transportElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();

((HttpsTransportBindingElement)transportElement).AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic; //it should HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate
((HttpsTransportBindingElement)transportElement).KeepAliveEnabled = false;

var messegeElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement
{
    MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None),
    ReaderQuotas = { MaxArrayLength = 200000, MaxBytesPerRead = 200000, MaxDepth = 200000, MaxNameTableCharCount = 200000, MaxStringContentLength = 200000, }
};

var bd = new CustomBinding(messegeElement, transportElement);
```

I checked the MessageVersion of the code below and Soap11 is where it should be 12. How do I use the code below to make it work with Soap12? I'm hoping this will make the connection work here.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
```

Comment: **CustomBindingThe username was not provided. Specify the username in ClientCredentials**. The reason for this problem is that **client.ClientCredentials.UserName** is not set up on your WCF client. You can instantiate your WCF client and set it up. The Content-Type of Soap 1.1 and Soap 1.2 is different. Soap 1.1 is **text/xml** and Soap 1.2 is **application/soap+xml**.